# Two conditions for scroll offset and element

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I trying to do is, show `.box-tocart` when scroll top bigger than `.product-info-main` offset top and also if reached to `.page-footer` should hide but I couldn't mix these conditions together, each condition work separately but not working together with `||` or `&&`

```js
var target = $('.product-info-main').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var footer = $('.page-footer').offset().top;
  var element = $('.box-tocart').offset().top;
  
  if (($(window).scrollTop() >= target) || (element >= footer)) {
    $('.box-tocart').show();
  } else {
    $('.box-tocart').hide();
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#nothing {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.product-info-main {
  height: 1000px;
}

.box-tocart {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nothing"></div>
<div class="product-info-main">
  <div class="box-tocart"></div>
</div>
<div class="page-footer"></div>
```

**Goal:** show `.box-tocart` if scroll top bigger than `.product-info-main` offset top, else hide. Also if reached to `.page-footer` hide, else show, but I want these two conditions together, but couldn't make it work.

The problem with current snippet is, it not hide `.box-tocart` after reach `.page-footer`

> Simple explanation: green div should show after red div, else hide and should hide after
>   reach to blue div else hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the condition to:

```
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  if ((scrollTop >= target) && (scrollTop + windowHeight <= footer)) {
    // ...
  }
```

Updated example:

```js
var target = $('.product-info-main').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var footer = $('.page-footer').offset().top;
  var element = $('.box-tocart').offset().top;
  
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  if ((scrollTop >= target) && (scrollTop + windowHeight <= footer)) {
    $('.box-tocart').show();
  } else {
    $('.box-tocart').hide();
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#nothing {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.product-info-main {
  height: 1000px;
}

.box-tocart {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nothing"></div>
<div class="product-info-main">
  <div class="box-tocart"></div>
</div>
<div class="page-footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(window).scrollTop()` instead of `element` so your OR condition should be like `if (... || $(window).scrollTop()  >= footer`, that’s because the scroll position is all relative to the window view and not to the cart box

I hope it can help you.

Comment: But I want to hide green div when this reach to blue div, not scrollTop of page.

Comment: Oh, so make something like, $(window).scrollTop() + $(“.box-tocart”).height;